# Issue in configuring elastichsearch.yml in 5.2.1 using rpm

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have installed elasticsearch 5.2.1 in my Linux box using rpm. Elasticsearch was installed successfully. When I tried to change the `path.log` and `path.data` attributes in `elasticsearch.yml` generated under `/etc/elasticsearch` elasticsearch service is getting down.

Below is the configuration I changed

```
cluster.name: cluster_1
node.name: data.node1
path.data: /root/myproject/data
path.logs: /home/elasticsearch/logs
```

Then I executed the following command

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

My elasticsearch service is not starting. When I commented the below lines. My service is up and running.

```
    path.data: /root/myproject/data
path.logs: /home/elasticsearch/logs
```

How can I overcome this problem. I am not sure whether I am committing the changes in right file.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the indentation of `path.data` actually the way you pasted it here? If so, that would be why it's not starting. Can you post the output of `systemctl status elasticsearch` ?

Comment: Isn't this a permission issue? It looks like you're running your elasticsearch with a specific linux user(elasticsearch) but then you try to point data to a root directory, you can try chown the data directory to belong to elasticsearch instead of root if this is the case.

Comment: @MarcosMaia. I am running it as root user. I didn't get any permission related erros.

Comment: @nir0s. I am getting below status when I use              `elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-03-17 02:59:04 PDT; 1min 27s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 20310 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet -Edefault.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Edefault.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Edefault.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

Comment: Well, the status doesn't provide enough information.. But assuming that the indentation is as it shows in your example.. It's a problem. The config needs to be a proper yaml file. Did you try to run elasticsearch directly not using systemd and provide it with the config? Also, you might wanna validate your config using an online yaml validation tool..

Comment: Also.. Is there at all a /home/elasticsearch dir?

Comment: How do you run elastic 5 as root? That seems to be the first issue here as it is hardly feasible, either you used some kind of workaround which might create side effects, or you are unsure as to which account run elasticsearch. Also, could you show the output in the elasticsearch logs?

Comment: @asettouf. I installed it using rpm. I started elasticsearch as service

Comment: So you're not necessarily running it as root (actually probably not), and could you start elasticsearch as a normal application (`bin/elasticsearch`)? What is the output? What do you have in the logs?

Comment: @asettouf. When I start it as normal application . I got an error `can't be run as root user` that's why I go with rpm service.

Comment: Perhaps you could start it without the root account then? Why is it not a possibility?

Comment: @asettouf. I found it in log. I am getting access denied exception. How too make elasticsearch to read my` path.data` location

Comment: Good job. Then you can answer your own question

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the path which I have mentioned in the `path.data' is not accessible by the elasticsearch service.

You can check the logs in `/var/log/elasticsearch`